# Find returns same path twice, but truncated

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression

I am running this `find` command:

```
find $HOME * -depth -type d -iname *bowtie* | grep "bowtie*-*1[^2]"
```

My expected out put is:

```
/home/user/Documents/scripts/bowtie1.3.0-linux-x86_64
/home/user/Documents/scripts/bowtie-1.3.0-linux-x86_64
```

But it return this:

```
/home/user/Documents/scripts/bowtie1.3.0-linux-x86_64
/home/user/Documents/scripts/bowtie-1.3.0-linux-x86_64
Documents/scripts/bowtie1.3.0-linux-x86_64
Documents/scripts/bowtie-1.3.0-linux-x86_64
```

How can I modify the `find` command to only show the first two results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are running `find` with several search paths that are the same.  You are using `$HOME` and whatever names `*` generate.  The `*` obviously expands to some directories that, among other things, include the names you are seeking.

Suggestion:

```bsh
find "$HOME" -type d -name 'bowtie*1.[!2]*'
```

The above also eliminates your `grep` by using the `-name` test more creatively.  You will need to quote any patterns that should not be expanded relative to the current directory before invoking `find`.

The pattern matches names starting with `bowtie` and then contains `1.n`, where `n` is not `2`. In place of `[!2]`, you could use `[13-9]` to force the match of an integer other than `2`, not just any character other than `2`.

Comment: Note that though it's likely not what the OP intended `grep "bowtie*-*1[^2]"` matches on lines that contain `bowti` followed by 0 or more `e`s followed by 0 or more `-`s followed by`1` and any character other than `2`. So it would match for instance on the second line of a file path such as `$'/home/user/foo\nbowti1/whatever/\nBOWTIE-12'`. So what your script does is radically different but is likely what the OP needs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I'm aware that the user may have confused globbing patterns and regular expressions. I made sure to describe the pattern I'm actually using though.

Answer (score 9):

That is because you are passing two arguments to `find`:

- Your `$HOME` directory
- `*` which is expanded by the shell to the full list of files and directories in the current directory which, presumably, is your `$HOME`.

So `find` will first search through `$HOME` and return things like `/home/user/foo` and then it will search through the list of files and directories you gave it which, since they are expanded by the shell, are paths *relative* to your current directory and therefore do not have the leading `/home/user`, and so it returns things like `foo`.